# Buggy auto conversion to string : In which code-smell would it fall and how should avoid one?

Tags: java, strings

Consider this Java code:

```
int rowIndex=8;
int offset=0;

libFuncCall.populate("B"+rowIndex+offset, data);
```

Here I mistakenly missed the fact that, resulting argument is a `String` though I had rowIndex and offset both `integer`s. 
The actual code would have been:

```
libFuncCall.populate("B"+(int)(rowIndex+offset), data);
```

Until I logged it, before finding:

```
log.debug("B"+rowIndex+offset); // It was B80 instead of B8
```

In my case, first input argument was a cell in Excel spreadsheet. It took me days, to find this bug.

In which code smell catagory would it fall and how should I avoid one?

Comment: It is not a code smell, just a misinterpretation of a single piece of code. A code smell is a bad trend in a collection of code files, typically a software product.I would say this is a mistake on the language designers' part. In an attempt to make things easier and better looking they made it more dangerous.

Comment: if this method is the only way to access fields, then it is a code smell - since you address a cell in excel by *row & column* - not by *cellID*... even if they look very similar (see #3 on my answer). The pure fact, that the OP did loose some hours on finding the issue is prove for itself. (see #1 on my answer, the interface is not simple enough) - on the other hand, if there are more way to populate cells and the OP did use a misleading one, well... then it would be no code smell... i think we don't have enough data yet to know for sure (+1 for that comment)

Comment: Yup. I wanted to keep things easy and raw (revisit-refactor later). As I was providing quickfix and kept the "using library provided Cell object+look more into library provided getCellValueByCellName()" as technical-dept. Also I was trying to have cell cordinates abstracted away by simple String cell names(e.g. B8) in my library-agnostic wrapper class. It backfired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### violates [KISS](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#Keep_it_simple_stupid_KISS):

you have to create an Cell ID where you could provide coordinates - coordinates are way simpler

### violates [principle of least astonishment](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-3-yellow/#Principle_of_Least_Astonishment)

*surprise:* this **cell id** is an aggregated key

### violates [implementation reflects design](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-5-blue/#Implementation_reflects_Design)

cell coordinates are used by design - an **cell id** is not was specified

### of course

the proper method signature would have been `libFuncCall.populate(String column, int row)`

Comment: I think one should add that in case ´libFuncCall.populate` is a 3rd party lib with a fixed API, a solution would be to create a wrapper for that call which requires coordinates and use that wrapper exclusively.

Comment: that sounds reasonable @DocBrown!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @MartinFrank I*d like to add:
[primitive obsession](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-primitive-obsession-and-how-can-we-fix-it-wh2f33ki)

While the code smell focuses on types I find it in the way you construct the string.

Whenever I have to combine a literal string with dynamic data I always use [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))
This would change  your code  to:

```
libFuncCall.populate(String.format("B%d",rawIndex+offset), data);
```

leaving no room for the mistake you made.

Comment: yes, very very right (+1)

Comment: Using `String.format` doesn't solve the "primitive obsession", it just works around it - you have to *remember* to do that each time. Using a specific type *encapsulates* that logic, so that the *easy* thing to do is correct: you "fall into the pit of success". So the final code would be `libFuncCall.populate(new CellId("B", rawIndex+offset), data);`, with the `CellId` class responsible for calling `String.format` when you need to interact with a lower layer that expects the identifier as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You're breaking [Curly's law.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/curlys-law-do-one-thing/#:%7E:text=Curly%27s%20Law%20is%20about%20choosing,your%20code%20won%27t%20do.)
Do only one thing.

Every piece of code you write should do only one thing.

```
"B"+rawIndex+offset
```

You want this piece of code to do three things:
Add two integers, convert the result of that to a string, concatenate two strings.

It does two of those things, converting to string and concatenating.

You avoid this by being explicit.

```
int rawIndex=8;
int offset=0;
Integer cellRowNumber = rawIndex + offset;
String cellAddress = "B" + cellRowNumber.toString(); 

libFuncCall.populate(cellAddress , data);
```

Comment: Obvious question: How do we know that "B" is a cell column?

Comment: @PeterM: The thing is that, I was completely missing the fact that I was in fact dealing with strings rather than integers, thought some java compile mechanism should notify/warn me beforehand. For a moment I thought, "I can only expect this in dynamically-typed python or javascript". Now I know, I could get away with having/using Cell object of/in API.

Comment: @PeterM it should be even better for cellAddress not be a string at all, but a structure representing an actual location: something like: cellAddress.RowNumber, cellAddress.ColumnLetters . If you want to get to the cell later on you have to break it apart later anyway, so best to not join it in a string in the first place.

Comment: @PieterB I agree that a structure/class would be a better approach.  But I think was being too subtle in my comment.  I was trying to imply that at the very least you should define *String cellColumn = "B";*, and then *String cellAddress = cellColumn + cellRowNumber.toString();* or even *String cell Address = makeCellAddress(cellColumn, cellRowNumber);*

Answer (score 2):

I think the fundamental issue here is **primitive obsession**, or **stringly typed code**: your `libFuncCall.populate` method lists its input as a string, and leaves the caller responsible for formatting that string correctly. Presumably, other methods also need a similar cell reference; and other places in the code generate one.

That leaves a number of responsibilities scattered around the code:

- Gluing together row and column references (currently the responsibility of the caller)
- Validating that the string is a sane reference (presumably `libFuncCall.populate` would need to throw or propagate an exception if I passed `"hello, world"` as the argument)
- Splitting the string back up again if needed (and related tasks such as incrementing to get the next cell in the same column, or the same row)

Using a separate row and column parameter (as Martin Frank suggests) would solve the immediate problem, but still leaves these responsibilities scattered: `libFuncCall.populate` has to recognise that `"hello, world"` isn't a valid column reference, and know how to combine the two arguments as a string if lower-level functions expect one.

All of these can be *encapsulated* in a type such as `CellReference`:

- If you construct an instance from separate row and column parameters, you can't make the mistake shown in the question
- The constructor can immediately validate those, so `libFuncCall.populate` can trust the value ("make invalid states unrepresentable")
- The `CellReference` instance can have separate accessors for column and row, or for a combined string, depending on what the ultimate low-level code actually needs
- The signature of `libFuncCall.populate` immediately makes clear what it needs, rather than needing additional comments describing the expected format of the string argument

So the final code would look like:

```
int rawIndex=8;
int offset=0;

libFuncCall.populate(new CellReference("B", rawIndex+offset), data);
```

A typo of `new CellReference("B"+rawIndex+offset)` would be a compile error (no single-argument constructor); a typo of `new CellReference("B"+rawIndex, offset)` would be an immediate run-time error ("B0" is not a valid column reference).

Comment: `new CellReference("B", rawIndex+offset)`. That sounds reasonable rather than specifying coordinates.